# Mako Mermaids/H2O Just Add Water: Why do mermaids fear cats?

Tags: tv, mythology, disney, h2o-just-add-water

I've been watching "Mako Mermaids" - a Netflix Original series... a sort-of sequel to "H2O - Just Add Water" (which I believe Disney-channel aired).

Anyway, a sort of running joke in the series, is the mermaids extreme fear of *cats* - which is aggravated by the fact that the "ex"-mermaid they board with owns a cat called "Poseidon".

I was wondering if there is an in-universe explanation for this irrational fear of cats - maybe from the first series "H2O - Just Add Water" or the animated series about the life of the mermaids?  Or perhaps there are some mythological sources that states "mermaids fears cats"?

If not, I guess I'll just have to assume it's because the mermaid looks like big fish, and/or because both cats and mermaids love seafood (competition for resources)...

Comment: The wiki says that when they encounter a cat in the first episode, it's the first time they've seen one.

Comment: Mermaids are kind of fish, cat kills fish, so mermaid fear cats... For me its obvious ^^

Answer (score -1):

I haven't watched the animated series, but as far as the original "H2O - Just Add Water" is concerned, I can answer your question with a definite "No" - there is no in-universe explanation.
This is no surprise, because all mermaids in the original series were land people who had been transformed by swimming in a magical water (the moon lake on Mako Island for all but one who was transformed at a similar place in Ireland (just mentioned, not shown))  at the right moment.
Neither beings who were born as mermaids nor mer*men* do exist in the original series.

Comment: This feels like guesswork, especially if you haven't seen the entire run of shows

Comment: I *have* seen the entire original series "H2O - Just Add Water", and this has definitely no fear-of-cats content. Maybe I should slightly reword my first sentence to make clear that my answer refers to that series